# php get string between two strings with offset

Tags: php

```
function getdatabetween($string, $start, $end){
    $sp = strpos($string, $start)+strlen($start);
    $ep = strpos($string, $end)-strlen($start);
    $data = trim(substr($string, $sp, $ep));
    return trim($data);
}
$dt = "Hello cat bye Hello dog bye";
echo getdatabetween($dt, 'Hello', 'bye');
```

How do I add the offset to this function?

Example:

```
$dt = "Hello cat bye Hello dog bye";
echo getdatabetween($dt, 'Hello', 'bye', 0); //result = cat
echo getdatabetween($dt, 'Hello', 'bye', 1); //result = dog
```

Comment: Is that really what you want? I'm not sure exactly what the practical usage is for but if you want to retrieve all occurances and not just the first, second etc. one by one you should consider using the regular expressions matching functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

The function strpos implements a offset param.

Try this

```
function getdatabetween($string, $start, $end, $offset){
        $sp = strpos($string, $start, $offset)+strlen($start);
        $ep = strpos($string, $end, $offset)-strlen($start);
        $data = trim(substr($string, $sp, $ep));
        return trim($data);
}
```

Comment: Only shows the second data. Third data does not show. I added a third data and offset=1 and 2 shows second data.